# UIBarButtonItem Custom Icon

Tags: ios, icons

I use the following line to create a UIBarButtonItem with a custom icon named import2x.png:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnImport = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"import2x.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(btnImport)];
```

The icon is a png that looks like this:

[image]

But here's how it looks when it is run on the simulator - a solid red square:

[image]

The icon is created using a transparent (alpha=0) background.

Any suggestions?  TIA.

Comment: Which is the size of your image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image in the link provided has an opaque background. If that is the same image you're using that's why it look's like a solid block.

It should be created with a transparent background, like this:

[image: Icon with transparency]

i.e. in Photoshop you should be able to see the background pattern like this:

[image: Fixed image in Photoshop]

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. Its working fine. I also share my output screenshot. u have to use small size of icon . but icon should be visible, no problem.

```
 UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Login-pin.png"] landscapeImagePhone:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Login-pin.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(PickerCancelClick:)];
```

[image]

The search image is my output.

Comment: Don't change your image format. when u download ya create any icon make it .png. After that u don't change the format otherwise it'll show solid full color

Answer (score 2):

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"g122.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(menuClieckd:)];
```

This worked for me